Terrafrom tries to drop cert before updating https proxy
I'm trying to destroy infra I currently have with terraform. I have multiple certificates specified and one https proxy.
resource "google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate" "app_cert" {
  for_each = var.apps
  project  = var.project_id
  name     = each.key
  managed {
    domains = [each.value.domain]
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "google_compute_target_https_proxy" "default" {
  project          = var.project_id
  name             = "default"
  url_map          = google_compute_url_map.default.id
  ssl_certificates = [for cert in google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.app_cert : cert.id]
  ssl_policy       = google_compute_ssl_policy.ssl_policy_restricted.id
}

The problem is that terraform tries to drop certificate before updating https proxy configuration. GCP does not allow for it.
Error: Error when reading or editing ManagedSslCertificate: googleapi: Error 400: The ssl_certificate resource 'projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow' is already being used by 'projects/XXX/global/targetHttpsProxies/default', resourceInUseByAnotherResource

Destroy plan looks like this:
.....

  # module.lb.google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.app_cert["airflow"] will be destroyed
  # (because key ["airflow"] is not in for_each map)
  - resource "google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate" "app_cert" {
      - certificate_id            = 4361497403370590700 -> null
      - creation_timestamp        = "2024-04-15T01:58:16.103-07:00" -> null
      - expire_time               = "2024-07-14T01:58:17.000-07:00" -> null
      - id                        = "projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow" -> null
      - name                      = "airflow" -> null
      - project                   = "XXX" -> null
      - self_link                 = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow" -> null
      - subject_alternative_names = [
          - "airflow.data.staging.XXX.com",
        ] -> null
      - type                      = "MANAGED" -> null

      - managed {
          - domains = [
              - "airflow.data.staging.XXX.com",
            ] -> null
        }
    }

  # module.lb.google_compute_target_https_proxy.default will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_compute_target_https_proxy" "default" {
        id                               = "projects/XXX/global/targetHttpsProxies/default"
        name                             = "default"
      ~ ssl_certificates                 = [
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow",
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/dbtdoc",
          + "projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/dbtdoc",
        ]
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
    
......

I tried to use lifecycle setting create_before_destroy and also depends_on on https proxy but it changed nothing.
Is there a way to force Terraform to apply changes to https proxy first before destroying cert itself?
I know I can just use
terraform apply -target module.lb.google_compute_target_https_proxy.default

and apply proxy manually first, then apply the rest of resources. But this seems like common situation so maybe there is some solution to make it work without manual fix.
Thanks
// EDIT
Well actually I cannot even do this apply -target because it also tries to drop cert anyway.
$ terraform apply -target module.lb.google_compute_target_https_proxy.default
data.google_project.XXX_data_staging: Reading...
data.google_project.XXX_data_staging: Read complete after 2s [id=projects/XXX]
module.iap.google_project_service.iap: Refreshing state... [id=XXX/iap.googleapis.com]
module.dbtdoc.google_service_account.run: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/serviceAccounts/cloud-run@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
module.lb.google_compute_ssl_policy.ssl_policy_restricted: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/global/sslPolicies/default-ssl-policy]
module.dbtdoc.google_storage_bucket.docs: Refreshing state... [id=XXX-dbtdoc]
module.dbtdoc.google_cloud_run_v2_service.app: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/locations/europe-west1/services/dbtdoc]
module.dbtdoc.google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.app: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/regions/europe-west1/networkEndpointGroups/dbtdoc]
module.iap.google_iap_client.default: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/brands/36056823150/identityAwareProxyClients/36056823150-31gkpade7jab1ujp9q6t9sceakqjv5ol.apps.googleusercontent.com]
module.dbtdoc.google_compute_backend_service.app: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/global/backendServices/dbtdoc]
module.lb.google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.app_cert["airflow"]: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow]
module.lb.google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.app_cert["dbtdoc"]: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/dbtdoc]
module.lb.google_compute_url_map.default: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/global/urlMaps/default]
module.lb.google_compute_target_https_proxy.default: Refreshing state... [id=projects/XXX/global/targetHttpsProxies/default]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
  - destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.lb.google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.app_cert["airflow"] will be destroyed
  # (because key ["airflow"] is not in for_each map)
  - resource "google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate" "app_cert" {
      - certificate_id            = 4361497403370590700 -> null
      - creation_timestamp        = "2024-04-15T01:58:16.103-07:00" -> null
      - expire_time               = "2024-07-14T01:58:17.000-07:00" -> null
      - id                        = "projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow" -> null
      - name                      = "airflow" -> null
      - project                   = "XXX" -> null
      - self_link                 = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow" -> null
      - subject_alternative_names = [
          - "airflow.data.staging.XXX.com",
        ] -> null
      - type                      = "MANAGED" -> null

      - managed {
          - domains = [
              - "airflow.data.staging.XXX.com",
            ] -> null
        }
    }

  # module.lb.google_compute_target_https_proxy.default will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_compute_target_https_proxy" "default" {
        id                               = "projects/XXX/global/targetHttpsProxies/default"
        name                             = "default"
      ~ ssl_certificates                 = [
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow",
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/dbtdoc",
          + "projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/dbtdoc",
        ]
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # module.lb.google_compute_url_map.default will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_compute_url_map" "default" {
        id                 = "projects/XXX/global/urlMaps/default"
        name               = "default"
        # (7 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - host_rule {
          - hosts        = [
              - "airflow.data.staging.XXX.com",
            ] -> null
          - path_matcher = "airflow" -> null
        }
      - host_rule {
          - hosts        = [
              - "dbtdoc.data.staging.XXX.com",
            ] -> null
          - path_matcher = "dbtdoc" -> null
        }
      + host_rule {
          + hosts        = [
              + "dbtdoc.data.staging.XXX.com",
            ]
          + path_matcher = "dbtdoc"
        }

      ~ path_matcher {
          ~ default_service = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/backendServices/airflow" -> "projects/XXX/global/backendServices/dbtdoc"
          ~ name            = "airflow" -> "dbtdoc"
        }
      - path_matcher {
          - default_service = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/backendServices/dbtdoc" -> null
          - name            = "dbtdoc" -> null
        }
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 1 to destroy.
╷
│ Warning: Resource targeting is in effect
│ 
│ You are creating a plan with the -target option, which means that the result of this plan may not represent all of the changes requested by the current configuration.
│ 
│ The -target option is not for routine use, and is provided only for exceptional situations such as recovering from errors or mistakes, or when Terraform specifically suggests to use it as part of an error message.
╵

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

module.lb.google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.app_cert["airflow"]: Destroying... [id=projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow]
module.lb.google_compute_url_map.default: Modifying... [id=projects/XXX/global/urlMaps/default]
module.lb.google_compute_url_map.default: Still modifying... [id=projects/XXX/global/urlMaps/default, 10s elapsed]
module.lb.google_compute_url_map.default: Modifications complete after 12s [id=projects/XXX/global/urlMaps/default]
╷
│ Warning: Applied changes may be incomplete
│ 
│ The plan was created with the -target option in effect, so some changes requested in the configuration may have been ignored and the output values may not be fully updated. Run the following command to verify that no other changes are pending:
│     terraform plan
│ 
│ Note that the -target option is not suitable for routine use, and is provided only for exceptional situations such as recovering from errors or mistakes, or when Terraform specifically suggests to use it as part of an error message.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error when reading or editing ManagedSslCertificate: googleapi: Error 400: The ssl_certificate resource 'projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/airflow' is already being used by 'projects/XXX/global/targetHttpsProxies/default', resourceInUseByAnotherResource
│


I need to remove cert from state
terraform state rm 'module.lb.google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.app_cert["airflow"]'

Then apply and then remove cert from GCP manually.
gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete airflow --project=XXX


Did you drop a key from the apps values? Because the output says (because key ["airflow"] is not in for_each map).

@MarkoE Yes. But this is what I want to do. I provide a map of apps with domains and TF module creates certs and add those to https proxy. When I want to remove an app (airflow in this case) I just remove it from the map and apply. TF should see that app was removed, then TF needs to drop cert for this app and update https proxy cert list. HTTP proxy depends on certs so in case of cert drop it should be updated first before actual cert drop is issued. This is not what TF tries to do. It first tries to drop cert and then update proxy.

Terraform builds a tree where it looks at resource dependencies. The output is usually displayed in alphabetical order, which does not mean the resources will be changed/deleted in that order.

@MarkoE I tried to apply and it failed because the order is wrong. There is error included from apply in my question. Take a look.

Mhm, ok, and is the result the same when not using -target? I mean, terraform should know how to handle that, but it also could be a bug in the GCP provider if it doesn't work.

@MarkoE Yes. Without target it is the same. I don't think it is a bug in provider. More like terraform not being smart enough to handle this destroy case. It knows exactly what to do when you add new cert. It will first create it and then update proxy configuration to add new cert to the list. It somehow does not do the opposite when destroying resources.

Been dealing with this for around 2 years now.  Upgrading to TF all the way to 6.6 doesn't help.  I've also tried using null_resource w/ depends_on but no luck there either.  Terraform typically picks up dependencies direct from the API, and is not seeing anything in this case.  There's a similar scenario where trying to remove a backend service that was part of a URL map.
